# Windows 10 extremely slow to unlock when using domain account

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-domain

I've just switched to a new laptop at work (Win10 Pro), and I'm having an infuriating problem where it takes 25-30 seconds to unlock when logged in using my domain account, when on the network.

- If I use my domain account on a different PC, everything is fine
- If I use a local account on the new PC, everything is fine
- If I RDP to the machine with my domain account, lock it, then unlock it, everything is fine
- If I disconnect the machine from the network before unlocking locally, everything is fine
- If I unlock locally, with AD account, while connected to the network, it takes 25-30 seconds.

I shut down every running application, then did a Wireshark capture while reproducing the problem - when I unlock, it briefly talks to our domain controllers for a second or two (as expected), then seems to spend about 20 seconds chatting TLS with login.microsoftonline.com.

If I block access from my PC to login.microsoftonline.com on our firewall, unlock times go down to about 4-5 seconds.  Unfortunately, this also breaks anything else that uses this (e.g. O365), so it's not a workable solution.

So it seems pretty clear there is *something* on this particular machine that is causing it to talk to Microsoft on every unlock, causing a delay - but I'm having little luck determining exactly what, or how to turn it off.

Does anyone have any idea what this might be, or even how I might go about finding out what it might be?

Disclaimer: I'm a networking/Linux guy, not so much a Windows/AD guy.

Comment: Based on your description you are probably referring to a computer that is Azure AD joined. You might be using Windows Hello or enterprise state roaming. There could be a problem with the device registration. You should ask your IT department to [troubleshoot your hybrid joined device](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/troubleshoot-hybrid-join-windows-current).